# When are fragments reattached?

Tags: android, android-fragments

When can fragments be reattached?

I'm wondering when in the activity and fragment lifecycles would a fragment be reattached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the fragment [lifecycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ3QW.png), the fragment is attached (the `onAttach` is called) once it is associated with an activity. Reattaching does not actually happen unless the fragment's association with its activity is over (the `onDetach` is called). And this is done by either calling the `detach()` method or destroying the parent `Activity`. Then when you re-associate the fragment with the activity, it'll be attached again and the cycle goes on.

Comment: So the fragment will only ever be reattached to the same type of activity?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but a Fragment can be attached to any FragmentActivity.

Comment: Suppose I have two subclasses of FragmentActivity, FragmentActivityX and FragmentActivityY. Both use SomeFragment.

FragmentActivityX is in the foreground and I tap back, which destroys FragmentActivityX and bring FragmentActivityY into the foreground. Since both FragmentActivities use SomeFragment, will the same SomeFragment instance from FragmentActivityX be reattached to FragmentActivityY?

Comment: No, it's not the same instance, so it won't be reattached to FragmentActivityX. Unless you declare the SomeFragment instance in FragmentActivityY as **static** and use it in FragmentActivityX.